# How to create regex javascript function to match certain combination of string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I just have a problem, to create a function to match this string combination.
The first part contain I, II, III, or IV. And then separated by / character. And then followed by A, B, C, or D.

So it would like III/A, IV/B, I/D.

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: here it is `^(?:II?I?|IV)\/[ABCD]$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a nice teaching opportunity.

First, you need `^` and `$` [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to make sure that the entire string matches the regex.

```
/^(regex)$/
```

Now, to match `I` through `III`, you can use the `{m,n}` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
/^I{1,3}$/
```

`IV` is different though. You will need to allow two [alternative matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). But to make sure that the alternation only includes the text and not the anchors, you need to enclose it in a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
/^I(?:I{0,2}|V)$/
```

The rest is straightforward. `\/` matches a slash, and since the four next alternatives are all exactly one character in length, you don't need to use alternation, but you can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/^I(?:I{0,2}|V)\/[ABCD]$/
```

Comment: Note that it is better to write: `^I(?:I{1,2}|V)?\/[ABCD]$` or `^I(?:II?|V)?\/[ABCD]$` because if the string begins with `IV` the first alternation doesn't succeed. `^I(?:V|I{0,2})?\/[ABCD]$` is also possible but doesn't put the most probable alternative at the first place.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Great ideas. It's nice to see how much thought one can put into such a (at first glance) trivial problem.

Comment: Simple cases are the best, in a more long pattern I will probably missed that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
.match("(I|II|III|IV)/[ABCD]")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/(I|II|III|IV)(\/)([A-D])/g
```

1. 1st Capturing group (I|II|III|IV)
   1st Alternative: I
   I matches the character I literally (case sensitive)
   2nd Alternative: II
   II matches the characters II literally (case sensitive)
   3rd Alternative: III
   III matches the characters III literally (case sensitive)
   4th Alternative: IV
   IV matches the characters IV literally (case sensitive)
2. 2nd Capturing group (/)
   / matches the character / literally
3. 3rd Capturing group ([A-D])
   [A-D] match a single character present in the list below
   A-D a single character in the range between A and D (case sensitive)
   g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)